# How to save user data globally in C++ Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Here is the button handler that helps to login a user, I will like to retrieve the user data into a global data structure that be used all through the program, something relating to PHP Web Session. How do I implement and retrieve using my code below

```
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;
private: System::Void loginBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ email = this->email->Text;
    String^ password = this->password->Text;

    if (email == " " || password == "") {
        MessageBox::Show("Please enter all fields to proceed");
    }
    else {
        String^ connString = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=";
        MySqlConnection^ connDb = gcnew MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand^ cmdDb = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from clocking.users where EMAIL = '" + email + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + password + "' ", connDb);
        MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
        try {

            connDb->Open();
            myReader = cmdDb->ExecuteReader();
            int row = 0;
            while (myReader->Read()) {
                row = row + 1;
            }

            if(row == 1){
                MessageBox::Show("Welcome on board! Auth Successful");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox::Show("Incorrect Email/Password Combination. Try again!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception^ex) {
            MessageBox::Show("Error Connecting to System Database!");
        }
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Lewa Bammy Stephen, your code is fine, you just have to add a class where you save the user data with its appropriate get and set methods, I show you below.

```
public bool Login(string Nombre, string Contraseña)
{
    using (var conection = Getconection())
    {
        conection.Open();
        using (var command = GetSqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = conection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Usuario where Usuario = @Usuario and claveusu =@claveusu";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Nombre);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claveusu", Contraseña);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Datoscahe.Iduser = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    Datoscahe.Name = reader.GetString(1);

                     Obtenerrol();


                }
                return true;

            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you look closely inside the while condition I am telling it to call the Data class cahe so that it saves me the information of the person who started the session indicating what type of value it has and the position it has in the database

```
namespace Capadatos.SQLserver
{
    public static class Datoscahe 
    {   
        public static int Idusuario { get; set; }
        public static string Nombre { get; set; }
        public static string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public static string Sexo { get; set; }
        public static DateTime Fecha_nacimiento { get; set; }
        public static string Num_documento { get; set; }
        public static string Direccion { get; set; }
        public static string Telefono { get; set; }
        public static string Email { get; set; }
        public static int Idrol { get; set; }
        public static string Usuario { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the class where I keep the user data

Comment: Thanks so much for the translation. I can call the get /set globally right?

Comment: yes, if you put it static you can call it from anywhere without having to create an instance